# How to close off a Git Branch?

Tags: git, github

I'm starting out using Git + GitHub.

In our distributed team, each member is creating their own branch for each issue/requirement they are allocated.

1. `git branch Issue#1     <-- create this branch`
2. `git checkout issue#1   <-- switch over to this branch`

now `code code`, `commit`, `code`, `commit`, etc...

then `pull request`, `code-fixup`, `commit`, `code`, `commit` .. etc.

and finally the pull request is accepted.

But, now what?

Does the person who created the branch on their local dev machine need to close off the branch? A suggestion was for the dev person to delete the branch `( ... -D ...)` and then do a pull / refresh of the master .. which then will get all their branch code.

Comment: A branch in Git is just a label on a specific commit - so basically, if you don't need it anymore - just delete that "branch" (that "label"  on that commit). Locally, just do a `git branch Issue#1 -d` and that's all there is - no code is lost, just a label is removed from your repository

Comment: @marc_s I suggest to just make an answer out of it :)

Comment: So @marc_s - you're saying that the standard practice once u've finsihed your branch .. and the branch has been pushed .. we delete it? What about merging?

Comment: @Pure.Krome At least I assumed, that by "pull request is accepted" you mean, that it is already merged. Yes, of course, integrate the changes into `master`, `develop`, or whatever your development branch is named (Merge, Rebase (with/without squash), ...)

Comment: when i said 'pull request is accepted' .. that happens somewhere else. (ie. the developer in charge who approves all the code that is PR'd...). I was wondering if i should switch over to master on MY local dev machine and do a merge also.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: yes, that's probably one good way to do it. After all: if you've pushed your changes to the central repo and the pull request has been accepted, the acceptor will most likely have merged those changes into some branch on the central repo - so next time around, when you pull from the central repo, you'll get your merged changes.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

We request that the developer asking for the pull request state that they would like the branch deleted. Most of the time this is the case. There are times when a branch is needed (e.g. copying the changes to another release branch).

My fingers have memorized our process:

```
git checkout <feature-branch>
git pull
git checkout <release-branch>
git pull
git merge --no-ff <feature-branch>
git push
git tag -a branch-<feature-branch> -m "Merge <feature-branch> into <release-branch>"
git push --tags
git branch -d <feature-branch>
git push origin :<feature-branch>
```

A branch is for work. A tag marks a place in time. By tagging each branch merge we can resurrect a branch if that is needed. The branch tags have been used several times to review changes.

Comment: We've made a recent change to our procedure. Using `git push --tags` is heavy handed and downloads all tags. This makes it difficult to have you're own local tags. Instead we use `git push origin branch-<feature-branch>` to push just the one tag.

Comment: So the last line, you need to remember to use the tag name for the feature branch, which we set previously to "branch-<feature-branch>", rather than just <feature-branch>. Correct?

Comment: @PremierBromanov the last line is for deletes remote branch. For remember the tag @BillDoor have used `git push --tags`.

Comment: Excelent script!!

Answer (score 42):

after complete the code first merge branch to master then delete that branch

```
git checkout master
git merge <branch-name>
git branch -d <branch-name>
```

Comment: and this is on MY own dev machine, right? the main person who accepts any new code .. his machine is elsewhere.

Comment: If somebody else is doing the merge, he has your branch pointer in a separate remote usually, e.g. sender/branch-name. He will need to use `git remote prune sender` to also get rid of it after you did - though in most cases, he need not care.

Comment: *You* should never merge your own branch unless you are the one responsible for integrating it in the main tree. If you aren't and you asked someone else to integrate it, update your master branch with the new remote commits - they should contain whatever you requested to be pulled - and then delete your branch. This ensures you won't have any problems if the other guy changed things.

Answer (score 41):

Yes, just delete the branch by running `git push origin :branchname`. To fix a new issue later, branch off from master again.

Comment: That will delete the remote branch, not the local one.

Comment: I don't know why this is modded at -2, this is the correct answer. They definitely have a remote branch, how else could they issue a PR against it?

Comment: If you do this, and then do a git pull, won't it then delete your local branch, as well? (Edit: nm, I see that it explicitly does not, unless you run git remote prune.)

Comment: What happens to the branch history?