# What's the difference between 'closing' and 'deleting' a branch?

Tags: git

What's the difference between 'closing' and 'deleting' a branch?

I see these two terms bandied about but I'm not sure what they mean precisely in the context of Git. Are they both effectively referring to the same thing (`git branch -d`) or is there some subtle difference of which I should be aware?

I may be wrong but so far my understanding is that, unless I tag the branch prior to deletion, once the branch is deleted there's no evidence left behind that it ever existed. Correct?

Comment: Perhaps it would help your cause to cite some examples. I have never seen the phrase "closing a branch".

Comment: Unless you GC your repository, your branch (or rather, all its commits) remain in the repository and can be found in different ways. Like `git fsck --lost-found` I found out about just now. `git reflog`, which keeps a record of actions taken on the repository, will also show you having made commits on the branch and having left it.

Comment: @StevenPenny
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6875572/git-branches-not-closing-after-merge
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614112/how-to-close-off-a-git-branch
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200643/can-you-close-branches-in-git

Comment: Looks like the answer is "No. No idealogical difference, just semantics." The proper git term is 'delete'.

It's terminology leakage from mercurial which has a "close-branch" option to leave it lying around in an archive/read-only state or some such.

Comment: for bitbucket, it seems closing and deleting are the same maybe: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-unmerged-branches/

Answer (score 7):

There is no explicit command in git that is referred to as a `close` it is possible that by convention, some programmers refer to a branch as "closed" when it is merged back into the project and is no longer being maintained. Sometimes the branch is kept around, other times it is deleted, but the idea is that it is not being used anymore.

To answer your second question, there are a few ways you can keep track of a branch after you delete it. The most common way is via a remote host. Running `git -d branch_name` will only destroy your local copy. The remote host will still have its version in case you need it later. You can also stash the branch you are about to delete and come back to it later. This is how you stash

```sh
git stash save "I'm saving this branch before I delete it because yolo"
```

Here is a link on how to use stash to achieve your end, but your end it an unusual use case:
https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html

Basically, if you stash your branch then you would have a record of its existence after deleting it. Additionally, if you merged that branch into other branches then those branches still know something about the existence of the deleted branch (mostly just that it existed). Again you can see what a given branch knows about its own merge history with `git log --graph`

There may be other ways that a branch can be seen in some fashion after deletion, but this should not be an issue for most workflows.

Comment: You can't stash a branch; `git stash` works only on changes in the working directory and the index. References to deleted branches will be kept for a while in Git's reflog, though.

Comment: @mipadi: stashing before deleting a branch would save a reference to the old branch HEAD via the stash list, but I wouldn't consider it a wise way to do things.

Comment: @siride: How? `git stash` only operates on changes in the working directory and the index. How does it save a reference to the branch?

Comment: @mipadi: `git stash` creates two commit objects, which would thus be references to whatever HEAD is at the time of stash. Stashes are tracked references, so everything they reference is also considered live and non-collectable.

Comment: @mipadi You can do the following which is basically stashing a branch, `git stash save "yo, saving this branch"` then later `git checkout stash@{0}` assuming that was the stash name that you saved. Then you will have your old stashed branch checked out as the current branch.

Comment: @IamJohnGalt: That will only work if you have uncommitted changes; otherwise, you'll get a message that no changes were stashed.

Comment: @siride: Only if you have uncommitted changes -- if you don't, `stash` doesn't do anything (and returns an error message indicating that's the case).

Comment: It's easy to try this out: create a repo, create a branch, run `git stash`: it'll say "No local changes to save" and no stash commits will be created.

Comment: @mipadi: I get that, but if you do have unsaved changes, stash will save your branch. It's kind of implicit in the basic understanding of stash.

Answer (score 4):

I've since come to appreciate that to "close a branch" roughly equates to to "delete all local and remote copies of the branch".

The difference is that *Deleting* the branch is just one technical sub-step of conceptually *Closing* the branch.

*Closing* is a broad reference to permanently removing a branch from the team's mindset which glosses over the messy details of merging, or abandoning, or whatever is necessary to make it a thing of the past.

Answer (score 1):

A branch in git is just a label pointing to some particular commit. Git itself doesn't have any idea of "closing" a branch. Perhaps you're talking about GitHub.com's pull request feature? That's not actually part of git itself. You can close a pull request on github so it no longer shows up in the open pull requests list, but that doesn't have any effect on the repository. It doesn't change any branches.